# How do I get the sum of index2 related to index1

Tags: python, for-loop

I've got a function where I get the frequency list below with the list

```
data_list = [(33, 60), (34, 64), (34, 1500), (34, 712), (35, 52), (35, 60), (36, 52), (36, 287), (37, 52), (37, 52), (37, 52), (39, 60), (40, 643), (40, 52)]
```

Now I do get the correct output of

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 12], [4, 2]]
```

where the first index relates to the range ie

```
0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49
```

now I'm trying to get the sum of the last variable by just changing count to

```
count+= index2[j]
```

but it is no longer related to the range and just picks the first 10 it seems, 
any thoughts on why this is happening?

```
    def get_freq_list(self):
        index1,index2 = zip(*data_list)
        a_list=[]
        for i in range(int(self.__size)):
            count=0
            for j in range(i*10,(i+1)*10):
                count+=index1.count(j)
            a_list.append([i,count])
        return a_list
```

expected output:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 3003], [4, 695]]
```

actual output:

```
[[0, 2891], [1, 807], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0]]
```

Comment: For readers that don't understand what the code is trying to do: for example, the range 40-49 is at index 4 in the list of ranges and the tuple values in data_list with the first element in the range 40-49 are (40, 643) and (40, 52), so adding the 2nd element values gives 643+52 => desired output is [4, 695]. Repeat for the other ranges.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter

bin_to_freq = Counter()

for num, freq in data_list:
    bin_ = num // 10
    bin_to_freq[bin_] += freq

max_bin = max(bin_to_freq.keys())

def output_helper():
    for bin_ in range(max_bin + 1):
        yield [bin_, bin_to_freq[bin_]]

print(list(output_helper()))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 3003], [4, 695]]
```